# Go websocket serialization/deserialization json

Tags: json, go, websocket

I'm using [gorilla](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/websocket) websocket, and i'm planing using json for serialization/deserialization.

Let say i have struct like this for receive the incoming messages:

```
type Foo struct {
    A string `json:"a"`
    B string `json:"b"`
}
```

and

```
type Bar struct {
    C string `json:"c"`
    D string `json:"d"`
}
```

gorilla provide `conn.ReadJSON` for receive incoming messages. The incoming messages can be Foo or Bar but i can't use `conn.ReadJSON(Foo)` and listen for other `conn.ReadJSON(Bar)`, it's a mess. I want something like just `conn.ReadJSON(Messages)`, like `JSON.parse()` in javascript. How to handle incoming messages if Foo is received, then it stored into `Foo` struct, and if Bar is received then it stored into `Bar` struct ?

I'm thingking the solution is using this struct:

```
type Messages struct {
    Control string `json:"control"`
    X // Data type for either Foo or Bar struct
}
```

The incoming messages now have json control, value of control can be Foo or Bar. Using `if else` if control==Foo then `X` is assign to Foo, else `X` is assign to Bar. But i can't figured the data type for `X`.

Any sollution is welcome, thankyou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [RawMessage](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#RawMessage).

```
type Messages struct {
  Control string `json:"control"`
  X json.RawMessage
}

var m Messages
err := c.ReadJSON(&m)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
switch m.Control {
case "Foo":
    var foo Foo
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(m.X), &foo); err != nil {
       // handle error
    }
    // do something with foo

case "Bar":
   ... follow pattern for Foo

}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your quick answer, that's really helping me. The solution is in the `encoding/json` and i realize i need to read more before asking, Thankyou once again.