# Callbacks in Gorilla/websocket

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I am trying to build a multiplayer backend in Go. I have worked in Node JS (socket.io) previously and I remember being able to register callbacks in my front-end for different messages like this :

```
  componentDidMount() {
this.socket.on('join_room', (clients) => {
  //do smt
});
this.socket.on('user_image', (data) => {
  // do smt
});
```

}

In gorilla/websockets I can only receive a general message from my backend. How can I differentiate between messages types? Is there any way to register some sort of callback similar to socket.io?

```
            let conn = new WebSocket("ws://" + document.location.host + "/ws/" + roomId);
            conn.onclose = function (evt) {
                let item = document.createElement("div");
                item.innerHTML = "<b>Connection closed.</b>";
                appendLog(item);
            };
            conn.onmessage = function (evt) {
                let messages = evt.data.split('\n');
                for (let i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                    let item = document.createElement("div");
                    item.innerText = messages[i];
                    appendLog(item);
                }
```

I am using this repo as an example for my backend code : https://github.com/AnupKumarPanwar/Golang-realtime-chat

Comment: Describe the type of the message in the message data and dispatch to specific functions based on that type.  For example use a JSON object with a string type field and a varying data field.

Comment: So you are saying to edit my message struct in client.go to something like this 
type message struct {
 name string
 data []byte
 room string
}
and then in my frontend check the "name" field and dispatch to different functions? 
Do you have any example by any means?

Comment: Does [Go websocket serialization/deserialization json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41111932/5728991) answer your question?

Comment: ah I see, thank you so much makes sense